# Named pipe (FIFO) halts execution when read and write are called

Tags: c, linux, process, ipc, named-pipes

Trying to create a process ring using named pipes for an assignment, and whenever I call read/write to those files it pauses the execution at that point. I've tried everything I could find for hours now, and have no idea why this is happening.

More context: Process ring with named pipes, passing a token between n processes, from a process i to i+1 in each loop.

Any help would be very much appreciated, and thank you for taking the time!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <errno.h>


#define MAX 50
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // File descriptors for pipes i and i+1 and token
    int fd1, fd2, token = 0;
    pid_t   pid;
    // Pipes path array
    char* fifos[2][MAX] = { "pipe1to2" , "pipe2to1" }
    
    
   ...
    
    //   Create pipes 
    for(int i =0 ; i < 2 ; i++){
        char* fileToCreate = fifos[i];
        if ((mkfifo(fileToCreate,S_IRWXU)) != 0) {
            if(errno == 17){ // If a file with the same name exists, this overwrites it 
                unlink(fileToCreate);
                mkfifo(fileToCreate,S_IRWXU);
            }else{
                printf("Unable to create a fifo; errno=%d\n",errno);
                exit(1);
            }                     
        }   
    }
     
    while(true){
        char* file = fifos[itr];
        fd1 = open(file,O_WRONLY);
        if(fd1 == -1){
            printf("Open error\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if(write(fd1,token,sizeof(int)) == -1){
            printf("Write error");
            return 2;
        }
        close(fd1);

        ...
    
    }

}
```

Comment: How exactly did you find out where your programs block? Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. With named pipes it is important to see the timing and order of the `open` calls in both processes. Citing https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html: *Normally, opening the FIFO blocks until the other end is opened also.* Why do you `open` and `close` the name pipe in a loop? After closing the write end, the read end will detect EOF; after closing read end, the write end will receive a SIGPIPE.